# ValueError in Django when running "python manage.py test"

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

I'm going through the Django tuturial from this site: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial05/

When I try to run "python manage.py test" i get the error message below:

Am running Django with PyCharm with python3.5. Does anyone know whats causing the problem and how to fix it?

my apps.py looks like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'polls'
```

and my models look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Here is the error message:

```
    Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Dropbox/WebPage/DjangoTestFolder/DjangoTest/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 532, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 482, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 726, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\creation.py", line 70, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 119, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, project_state)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 51, in state_forwards
    state.reload_model(app_label, self.model_name_lower)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 148, in reload_model
    self.apps.render_multiple(states_to_be_rendered)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 296, in render_multiple
    model.render(self)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 585, in render
    body,
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 158, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 307, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 706, in contribute_to_class
    super(ForeignObject, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name, virtual_only=virtual_only)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 306, in contribute_to_class
    lazy_related_operation(resolve_related_class, cls, self.remote_field.model, field=self)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 86, in lazy_related_operation
    return apps.lazy_model_operation(partial(function, **kwargs), *model_keys)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 84, in <genexpr>
    model_keys = (make_model_tuple(m) for m in models)
  File "E:\Dropbox\Python\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\utils.py", line 13, in make_model_tuple
    app_label, model_name = model.split(".")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: please Update your question with models.py and apps.py

Comment: @RasmusRavnFrost Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38029534/edit) the question to include the code rather than linking to an external source.

Comment: Ok, Ravi, I have added the files you requested. 
Also I added a public fork on bitbucket that should show the project in its entirety if needed, on this link:
https://bitbucket.org/RasmusRavnFrost/djangotestingforstackoverflow/src/52df96701310?at=master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in [polls/migrations/0001_initial.py line no 36](https://bitbucket.org/RasmusRavnFrost/djangotestingforstackoverflow/src/52df9670131089d70467ad6969940faa98f73732/DjangoTest/polls/migrations/0001_initial.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#0001_initial.py-36) `to='polls.models.QUESTION'`

```
field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.models.QUESTION'),
```

it should be `to='polls.Question'`

```
field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Question'),
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm now :) Any idea how that the error got there? Because I never made any manual changes in the polls/migrations/0001_initial.py file.

Comment: @RasmusRavnFrost i am unable to reproduce the error with your code wondering why this error occurred!

Comment: Well, I guess it's a mystery why then. After working with it some more, my best guess is that the error arose, because I made som changes in models.py, but didn't migrate them properly. I might have left the "manage.py runserver polls" running while doing migrations, which may be a problem. But that's all pure speculation.
Thanks anyways.